# jQuery rounding problem with .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textbox where a user inputs a number, like: 105.14 When I use jQuery to read it:

```
alert(parseInt($("#Info").val()));
```

It displays "105".

Why can't I get the remaining .14????

I'm sure it's something obvious....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because you are using **parseInt()**, which is rounding.

Try **parseFloat()** instead.

Comment: i've looked at this code about 200 times today, and tried using .toFixed(2) and doing a parseFloat afterwards, i did not see I was doing a parseInt.... Sometimes you just need another set of eyes, thanks..